# Restore Gitlab after accidentally deleting bin folder

Tags: git, centos, gitlab, centos7, restore

I have Gitlab CE on my CentOS 7 server along with Jetbrains Teamcity. While updating TeamCity, it asked me to upgrade **git to version** higher than *2.1.0*, because after the update it will not work with versions prior to 2.1.0. So I updated it as shown in [here][1]

after installation of a newer version of git (*2.24.1*), my Gitlab stopped working.
I think the step `sudo yum remove git*` removed not only my git but binaries of my GitLab. Because now there is no `bin` folder in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/` path (where gitlab-ctl gitlab-rake etc were kept).

The automatic backups were not set up, the `/var/opt/gitlab/backups/` folder is empty. How do I restore my GitLab, without losing my repositories and configurations?

PS this far I have backed up:

1. /opt/gitlab -> /opt/gitlab-backupd
2. /var/opt/gitlab -> /var/opt/gitlab-backupd
3. /etc/gitlab -> /etc/gitlab-backupd

And I want to run `yum install gitlab-ce`, but I'm afraid that I'll lose my repositories.
[1]: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-version-of-git-git-2-x-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer, in case if it helps anyone.

So, I went ahead and ran the install command, which did NOT remove any of existing data. However it did not run, neither did it reconfigure.
`gitlab-ctl status` showed that **postgres was down**.

Turns out `yum install gitlab-ce` **installed latest version** (13.4 at the time of writing), which was incompatible with existing embedded postgres version (9.6).
I had to find which version was installed previously and install desired version - 10.4.2 (changelog can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md))

Finally after installing the compatible version, setting up and running it - it was giving me the 502 error. `gitlab-ctl tail` showed that server denied access on */var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket* file. After deleting the file, everything was up and running).